# Loops and list-comprehension cannot find varibales when they are created using exec

Tags: python

In my (simplified) script I have the following:

```py
def predict(new_data):
 .
 .
 .
 model_list = fetch_needed_models() # ["f1","f2","f3"]

 for m in model_list:
      with open(f"./{m}.pkl","rb") as file:
          exec(f"{m}=pickle.load(file)")

 print(dir()) # [...,'f1','f2','f3',...]

 # Try with list-comprehension
 f1_pred = [f1.predict(x) for x in new_data] # NameError: name 'f1' does not exists
 
 # Try with loop
 f1_pred = []
 for x in new_data:
    f1_pred.append(f1.predict(x)) # NameError: name 'f1' does not exists
```

If I run the lines outside of a function, i.e just running the lines one by one (in VScode, interactive window) it works fine, but when I run the function like `python main.py` I get a `NameError: name 'f1' is not defined` error. I thought that maybe `exec` wasn't executed correctly but `print(dir())` after the `exec` commands shows, that the variables are indeed there.

Any one got any idea why?

**EDIT**

A simple test like

```py
def test():
    exec("f= []")
    f.append(2)
    print(f)

if __name__=="__main__":
 test()
```

```bash
> python test.py
>      "NameError: name "f" is not defined
```

also fails

Comment: Why would you use `exec` for this at all? A much better practice would be to have `inputs = {}`, and then `input[m] = pickle.load(file)`; dynamically generated variables defeat static analysis tools and are generally a code smell.

Comment: If you do that, you can then use `input["f1"].predict(x)`

Comment: Mind, if you have an arbitrary number of models, why you'd ever want to refer to just `f1` is a little unclear. Wouldn't it make more sense to do something like `for model in input.values(): pred = [model.predict(x) for x in new_data]`?

Comment: exec(f"f2=[]")
f2.append(5)
print(f2)  works. Could you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy since the models are used further down in the script (and those models are refered to by their name in the `model_list` e.g `pred_f1 = f1.predict()`).

Comment: @kubatucka Unfortunatetly not. The example provided is (almost) identical to the real code (`f1` and `f2` are dictionaries where `f3` is a class). And actually, it doesn't work with me that test (have editted the question)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it isn't that easy, unfortunately. A lot of stuff is going on with each model further in the script

Answer (score 1):

If you really do want to use `exec` (you shouldn't, and you should refactor your code to avoid it), you have to pass the environment in which the code is to be executed. Using your simplified example, you can do this:

```py
def test():
    exec("f= []", globals())
    f.append(2)
    print(f)

if __name__=="__main__":
 test()  # [2]
```

Comment: Note: This makes the code non-reentrant, thread-unsafe, etc., because instead of per-call locals, you're using the shared global namespace. You *could* pass some other `dict` as the locals, then use `otherdict['f']`, but in the OP's case, they may as well skip `exec` entirely.

Comment: I totally agree, that is why I put the disclaimer in the beginning that OP shouldn't use `exec` and it is a bad practice. But the question was specifically on how to make `exec` work in this context.

Comment: You could also do exec("global f") then exec("f = []") just define f as a global first.

Answer (score 0):

Locals are a compile-time feature; you can't add *real* locals to a function at runtime, even with `exec`. At compile-time, the size of the fixed-size array of locals is computed, and each name is assigned an index in that array; the array can't be expanded, and unrecognized names have no mappings. You can fake it with `locals()` (which copies the real locals and is then a `dict` that can be mutated), but don't.

Just use a `dict` keyed by the names you care about:

```
def predict(new_data):
 .
 .
 .
 model_list = fetch_needed_models() # ["f1","f2","f3"]

 models = {}
 for m in model_list:
      with open(f"./{m}.pkl","rb") as file:
          models[m] = pickle.load(file)

 # Try with list-comprehension
 f1_pred = [models['f1'].predict(x) for x in new_data]
 
 # Try with loop
 f1_pred = []
 for x in new_data:
    f1_pred.append(models['f1'].predict(x))
```

If you *know* `f1` will always be in there, you could extract it directly, but that sort of defeats the purpose of dynamically specifying the models:

```
def predict(new_data):
 .
 .
 .
 model_list = fetch_needed_models() # ["f1","f2","f3"]

 models = {}
 for m in model_list:
      with open(f"./{m}.pkl","rb") as file:
          models[m] = pickle.load(file)

 # We're sure f1 will be there, so we can make it a local manually    
 f1 = models['f1']

 # Try with list-comprehension
 f1_pred = [f1.predict(x) for x in new_data]
 
 # Try with loop
 f1_pred = []
 for x in new_data:
    f1_pred.append(f1.predict(x))
```